# How to remove \n, \", \\, etc. from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I basically want the effect of:

`str = str.replace('\\n', '\n').replace('\"', '"')...`

Some answers for this seem to be 'encode then decode', but that only works in Python2 (I'm using Python3). I've tried the str.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape'), but I've read 'unicode_escape' is deprecated, and it seems to replace non-ASCII characters with unicode code points on output.

A better illustration:

```
s = '\\"こんにちは\\"'
print(s)
s = s.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
print(s)
```

Output:

> \"こんにちは\"
>   "ããã«ã¡ã¯"

What I want:

> "こんにちは"

**Edit:** (for everyone saying just use `.replace()`)

The above is a simple example; more complex could be `s = r'こんにちは\\n'` which should convert to `r'こんにちは\n'`, for example. If I just replace all instances of `r'\\'` with `r'\'` and instances of `r'\n'` with `'\n'`, it won't handle cases where the escape character itself is escaped.

Maybe I could roll my own solution to this - but I prefer to use a language feature, if possible.

Comment: Per [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue21331) the accepted solution you referenced is deprecated and boils down to a hand rolled regular expression, which is generally not a very high quality option (poor readability, hard to catch all cases, etc)

Comment: Assuming you're disputing the duplicate closure: If the question is the same, it's a duplicate. If the answers are bad, post a better one. Do you think reopening your question would get you better answers?